# 'Cloud' filesystem storage does not work - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, storage

I am trying to save in the 'cloud' some files.

Using: `Storage::disk('local')->put('filename', $file)` works.

Using 's3' disk also works: `Storage::disk('s3')->put('filename', $file)`

BUT

when trying 'cloud': `Storage::disk('cloud')->put('filename', $file)` it returns the following error:

```
BadMethodCallException in PluggableTrait.php line 85: Call to undefined method League\Flysystem\Filesystem::createDriver
```

Any idea why and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `cloud` a possible option for the storage? I think you get the error because there is no driver for `cloud`

Comment: @mimo is right: 'cloud' is not a valid driver. The options are 'local', 's3', 'ftp', and 'rackspace'.

Comment: Thanks. What use is the "cloud" => "s3" that is in the filesystem config file then if it cannot be used? Even in L5.1 doc they use it...or am I wrong?

Comment: It's the default cloud driver. You could also use `rackspace`

Comment: Yes it is. But how do you tell Storage to store on the cloud ?

Comment: No offence man, but do you understand what "the cloud" is?

Comment: Guys - yes I know what cloud is ha-ha - what just look at the docks. They write : Storage::disk('cloud') meaning it is supposed to grab the default cloud service you set up meaning in my case => s3 . now that's my pb it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

Two years late to the party, but to help those that might find this post as I did. I believe what you want is...

Correct, only if you have a `disk` named 'cloud'.

```
$url = Storage::disk('cloud')->put('filename', $file);
```

Else; this uses the disk matching the name entered in `config('filesystem.cloud')`.

```
$url = Storage::cloud()->put('filename', $file);
```

Comment: Any Idea on how to make this `$request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');` use the cloud disk?

Comment: Try adding this before the code above `$file = $request->file('avatar');` @IvánSánchez

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this into a controller, what you should do is:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Cloud;

......

public function test(Cloud $cloud) {
    $cloud->...
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Is there a way to use Storage::cloud()... like this?

Comment: @Herrero, creo que podría se así  en el archivo `filesystems.php`     `'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),` el `s3` seria un `disks` configurado.